# LongPress on ListView with hyperlink on Android

Tags: android, listview, hyperlink, long-press

I'm developing an application in Android which displays a ListView element into a Fragment.
I want to put an hyperlink on the contextual menu that shows when you long press on an item of the list, but I'm founding difficulties doing that.

I'm already familiar on how to make a text with hyperlink in Android using the

```
TextView t1 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text1);
t1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

method but I'm not able to retrieve the appropriate hyperlink (that I have in the strings.xml XML file)

**The following is the XML file in which you can find the text1**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        ..
        android:text="@string/perm_internet"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        ..
        android:text="@string/perm_contacts"/>
```

**The following is the strings.xml file**

```
<resources>

    <string name="perm_internet"><a href="http://first_link">Internet</a></string>
    <string name="perm_contacts"><a href="http://second_link">Contacts</a></string>

</resources>
```

I want that when I long press on item1 on list it shows an hyperlink with the first link and that when I long press on item2 it shows second_link.

Would really appreciate some hints on how to do that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Include the following in the TextView definition in XML file:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:autoLink="web"/>
```